# CakePHP's CakeTime format for minutes

Tags: cakephp

I don't understand the result of CakeTime::format when using %i.

debug(CakeTime::format('2014-01-10 15:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'));
outputs false

debug(CakeTime::format('2014-01-10 15:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:xx'));
outputs 2014-01-10 15:xx

What is the correct format for minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html#CakeTime%3a%3aformat)

The formatting uses the option from [strftime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php). And "M" is the right parameter for minute, as @user2711870 said.

However, CakePHP documentation is wrong:

```
// called via TimeHelper
echo $this->Time->format('%F %jS, %Y %h:%i %A', '2011-08-22 11:53:00');
// August 22nd, 2011 11:53 AM
```

This should be

```
echo $this->Time->format('2011-08-22 11:53:00', '%F %jS, %Y %h:%M %A');
```

Comment: I linked your pull request :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using M uppercase

`debug(CakeTime::format('2014-01-10 15:25:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'));`

In this case appears correctly as you wish to appear.